# What are the differences among "make noise", "make a noise", "make noises"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

It seems that

"**make noise**: *emit a noise* (could be any noise such as one from music, TV, people talking, ...)" [Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/make+noise)

"**make a noise (about something)**: *(informal) to complain loudly* (talking about human only)" [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/noise?q=noise)

"**make noises (about something) (informal)**:

1. *to talk in an indirect way about something that you think you might do*

The company has been making noises about closing several factories.

2. *to complain about something"* [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/noise?q=noise)

But I am not sure if my research is right or not?

Answer (score 2):

*Noise* can be countable (refering to individual sounds that are noises) or non-countable (refering to a stream of sound with qualities like noise).  So *make a noise* does not automatically mean "complain" and *make noise* can mean this too.

*Make [a/some] noise about X* can be figuratively used to mean "doing something to gain attention about X" but I'm not sure that association is strong enough to really be an "official" well-known saying, but certainly a strong implication.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add that with children you might say "make a noise" "make a sound" "don't make a sound". What noise does a dog make? What does a cow say?"

Or in general, my refrigerator is making weird noises. It's making a whistling sound.

Make noise to complain, yes I've seen it. But I don't hear it in common speech very often. Oh, the neighbors are making a lot of noise. (I would interpret that first as they are having a party and making a noise disturbance instead of them "complaining about something". )